# Searching for a value from a specific cell on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am using userforms to input data, at a certain point part of the data is copied to one of the sheets in the workbook.

My code then needs to use one of the values in the sheet to check if this value apears on another sheet, if it does it copies values linked to that value to the original sheet and then populates the userform so that further info can be captured.

If I activate `on error resume next` everything works except the tab function stops working on the userform, if I run it without `on error resume next`, I get run-time error:

> '91' Object variable or with block variable not set.

How do i fix this?

```
Sub Find_7_day()

        Dim vfind

        Dim rng As Range

        Sheets("Test Data").Select
        Sheets("Test Data").Range("$E$3").Select
        vfind = ActiveCell

        'On Error Resume Next
        Call Sheet
        Set rng = Cells.Find(What:=vfind, After:=ActiveCell,        LookIn:=xlValues, _
             LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,     SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
             MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

       If ActiveCell = vfind Then
            Call Old_7_day
            Call Form_7_day_fill
        Else
            Sheets("Test Data").Select
        End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Your value is not being found and hence you are trying to activate a non-existent range. What is `Sheet`?

Comment: Remove the `.Activate` and test for `If Not rng Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Like @TimWilliams mentions, you cannot set a range and activate it at the same time. remove the `.Activate` ..if you want to select the cell, then next line could be `rng.select`---["Find Data in another sheet](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Find%20Data%20in%20other%20Sheet)

Comment: @SJR Sheet is another piece of code that takes you to the sheet in which the search is to be done, there are about 15 sheets to check so one of the inputs is used to locate the sheet and the other for this piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare and `.Activate` a variable `range` at the same time:

```
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Cells.Find(What:=vfind, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
         LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
         MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

suggestion, avoid using `.Select` and `Activate`, explanation here [How to Avoid the Select Method in VBA & Why](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/how-to-avoid-the-select-method/)

Code:

```
Sub Find_7_day()

        Dim vfind As String
        Dim rng As Range

        vfind = Sheets("Test Data").Range("$E$3").Value

        Call Sheet

        Set rng = Cells.Find(What:=vfind, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True, _
        SearchFormat:=False)

        If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox vfind & " " & "dont exist"
        Exit Sub
        End If

       If rng.Value = vfind Then
            Call Old_7_day
            Call Form_7_day_fill
        Else
            Sheets("Test Data").Select
        End If

        Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: @SJR Thank you, updated my answer to check if rng is nothing

Comment: Apologies, it was me, inadvertently. I have now reversed it. It seems that if you downvote and then upvote it goes from -1 to +1!